# What does it mean when saying "to be assigned something"| ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, variable-assignment

I was reading a book about Learning ASP.NET Core API when I run to a part saying:

> We create a private read-only field _repository **that will be assigned
> the injected MockCommandAPIRepo object** in our  constructor and used
> throughout the rest of our code.

Here is some text I thought you'd better have:
[image]

Then there are some explanations related to the picture above:

> 1. Add the new using statement to reference ICommandAPIRepo.
> 2. We create a private read-only field _repository **that will be assigned the injected MockCommandAPIRepo** object in our constructor
>    and used throughout the rest of our code.
> 3. The Class constructor will be called when we want to make use of our Controller.
> 4. At the point when the constructor is called, the DI system will spring into action and inject the required dependency when  we ask for
>    an instance of ICommandAPIRepo. This is Constructor  Dependency
>    Injection.
> 5. We assign the injected dependency (in this case  MockCommandAPIRepo) to our private field (see point 1).
>
> And that’s pretty much it! We can then use _repository to make use of our
> concrete  implementation class, in this case MockCommandAPIRepo. As
> I’ve stated earlier, we’ll reuse this pattern multiple times through
> the rest of the  tutorial; you’ll also see it everywhere in code in
> other projects – take note.

Now, According to the highlighted part above in number 2, I got a little confused!
I've heard of "to be assigned by some value" before, but here, it is saying that:

> that will **be assigned the injected MockCommandAPIRepo object** in our constructor

and as you see, there is no "**by**" added before **the injected MockCommandAPIRepo object...**.
So, I have a question now. What does it mean by the highlighted part above in number 2?
Does it mean the same when we add "by" in the sentence? or not?

Comment: "X will be assigned Y" means that "X := Y" will happen.

Comment: @peer What does ":=" mean??

Answer (score 1):

This is about `dependency injection` in Asp.Net Core. After we register service to the `IOC Container`, How to use it in our controller? We can inject them in controller via `Constructor Injection`. Once we register a service, the IoC container automatically performs constructor injection if a service type is included as a parameter in a constructor. In your question, An `IoC container` will automatically pass an instance of `ICommandAPIRepo(MockCommandAPIRepo)` to the constructor of `CommandsController`. Now we can use `MockCommandAPIRepo` in the constructor. But it can only be used in constructor, How can we use it in other method in `CommandsController`? Here we use:

```
private readonly ICommandAPIRepo _repository;
```

to create a global variable in `CommandsController`, Then in constructor, We use:

```
_repository = repository
```

assign the value of `repository` to `_repository`. Now `_repository` and `repository` has the same value, Because `_repository` is a global variable, So We can use `_repository` in other method in `CommandsController`. The whole process of dependency injection is done.

Comment: Hi @Hossein, If my answer help you solve your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks you very much.